# How to disable a sharepoint 2010 list column through sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list and I want to disable a single-line-of-text column. How can i do this through SharePointDesigner? Also, how can I set this field read-only through SharePointDesigner?

Comment: you can also use Sharepoint Manager 2010 for hide list column.

Comment: I can't use a third party tool in the company but I'll try to use it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via Infopath easily.

In infopath, select the textbox and right click, and at Textbox properties, select display and check read only. So simple at Infopath designer.

Also you can open infopath from the sharepoint menu.(When clicked List)

Comment: Thank you, @alicanbatur. After some researches, I had found this. It was really easy through InfoPath.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, disable mean remove from view? delete the column?

Cause in SharePoint designer, if you go in List and Libraries, open your list, and then all the column appearm you can remove the one you want.
If it's for the view, Process is quite the same, just edit the view rather than the list.

Comment: Actually, "disable" means changing text box type into read-only. I did this through JQuery. Soon after that, I found the "read-only" check box on InfoPath :) Thank you for your answer.